# How to remove duplicate characters in a string and print according to the longest occurrence

Tags: python, python-2.7

I've been trying to solve this program, but i am unable.

```
x="abcaa" # sample input
x="bca" # sample output
```

i have tried this:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
def f(x):
    print ''.join(OrderedDict.fromkeys(x))
t=input()
for i in range(t):
    x=raw_input()
    f(x)
```

The above code is giving:

```
x="abcaa" # Sample input
x="abc" # sample output
```

More Details:
Sample Input:

```
 abc
 aaadcea
 abcdaaae
```

Sample Output:

```
abc
adce
bcdae
```

In first case, the string is="abcaa", here 'a' is repeated maximum at the last so that is placed at last so resulting "bca" And in other case, "aaadcea", here 'a' is repeated maximum at the first so it is placed at first, resulting "adce".

Comment: Think you need to describe the problem in a bit more detail. It's not clear why the sample output `"bca"` is 'correct'.

Comment: What's "the first longest occurence"?

Comment: Still not clear. Sequences of the character whis is occuring in the longest sequence shall be replaced by one character but single occurences shall be removed???

Comment: This is not a consistently defined question. In your sample input and output, in the second example you are keeping the first `a`, but in the third example, you are keeping the last `a`. In your very first line you are keeping the last `a` as well.

Comment: sir, duplicate characters should be removed and that character should be placed in the position where there is a maximum repetition.
In first , the string is="abcaa", here 'a' is repeated maximum at the last so that is placed at last so resulting "bca"
And in other case, "aaadcea", here 'a' is repeated maximum at the first so it is placed at first, resulting "adce"

Comment: If I understand correctly the problem consists of two parts, eliminate all contiguous subsequences of each character except for the longest, replace the remaining subsequence with a single occurrence of that character. This must be done for every character in the string. All of  your examples only contain `a` repeated though, must the implementation handle something like `'aaabbaaacbbbbb'` -> `'acb'`?

Comment: yes sir, thank god you understood my question :d

Comment: @SíðhärthPátñàík: [My second answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25560285/908494) gives the same results as your sample output in your latest edit, and also gives the same result in Ryan Haining's comment. Does that mean I correctly guessed what you want, or not?

Comment: @SíðhärthPátñàík: So if Ryan Haining's comment and my second answer both guessed right (after a half dozen incorrect guesses from both me and other people), can you think of a way to rewrite your question so that people will understand it on the first try? Because I think there's a very good question struggling to get out here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking a different guess at what you want:

For each character, you want to find the position at which it has the most repetitions.

That means that, as you go along, you need to keep track of two things for each character: the position at which it has the most repetitions so far, and how many. And you also need to keep track of the current run of characters.

In that case, the `OrderedDict` is necessary, it's just not sufficient. You need to add characters to the `OrderedDict` as you find them, and remove them and readd them when you find a longer run, and you also need to store a count in the value for each key rather that just use the `OrderedDict` as an `OrderedSet`. Like this:

```
d = collections.OrderedDict()
lastch, runlength = None, None
for ch in x:
    if ch == lastch:
        runlength += 1
    else:
        try:
            del d[lastch]
        except KeyError:
            pass
        if runlength:
            d[lastch] = runlength
        lastch, runlength = ch, 1
try:
    del d[lastch]
except KeyError:
    pass
if runlength:
    d[lastch] = runlength
x = ''.join(d)
```

---

You may notice that there's a bit of repetition here, and a lot of verbosity. You can simplify the problem quite a bit by breaking it into two steps: first compress the string into runs, then just keep track of the largest run for each character. Thanks to the magic of iterators, this doesn't even have to be done in two passes, the first step can be done lazily.

Also, because you're still using Python 2.7 and therefore don't have `OrderedDict.move_to_end`, we have to do that silly delete-then-add shuffle, but we can use `pop` to make that more concise.

So:

```
d = collections.OrderedDict()
for key, group in itertools.groupby(x):
    runlength = len(list(group))
    if runlength > d.get(key, 0):
        d.pop(key, None)
        d[key] = runlength
x = ''.join(d)
```

---

A different way to solve this would be to use a plain-old dict, and store the runlength and position for each character, then sort the results in position order. This means we no longer need to do the move-to-end shuffle, we're just updating the position as part of the value:

```
d = {}
for i, (key, group) in enumerate(itertools.groupby(x)):
    runlength = len(list(group))
    if runlength > d.get(key, (None, 0))[1]:
        d[key] = (i, runlength)
x = ''.join(sorted(d, key=d.__getitem__))
```

However, I'm not sure this improvement actually improves the readability, so I'd go with the second version above.

Answer (score 2):

The `OrderedDict` isn't helping you at all, because the order you're preserving isn't the one you want.

If I understand your question (and I'm not at all sure I do…) the order you want is a *sorted* order, using the number of times the character appears as the sorting key, so the most frequent characters appear last.

So, this means you need to associate each character with a count in some way. You could do that with an explicit loop and `d.setdefault(char, 0)` and so on, but if you look in the [`collections`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/collections.html) docs, you'll see something named `Counter` right next to `OrderedDict`, which is a:

> dict subclass for counting hashable objects

That's exactly what you want:

```
>>> x = 'abcaa'
>>> collections.Counter(x)
Counter({'a': 3, 'b': 1, 'c': 1})
```

And now you just need to sort with a `key` function:

```
>>> ''.join(sorted(c, key=c.__getitem__))
'bca'
```

If you want this to be a stable sort, so that elements with the same counts are shown in the order they first appear, or the order they first reach that count, then you *will* need `OrderedDict`. How do you get both `OrderedDict` behavior and `Counter` behavior? There's a [recipe](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/collections.html#ordereddict-examples-and-recipes) in the docs that shows how to do it. (And you actually don't even need that much; the `__repr__` and `__reduce__` are irrelevant for your use, so you can just inherit from `Counter` and `OrderedDict` and `pass` for the body.)

Comment: Okay Sir,
I am explaining..
if the input is "abcaa" --> output "bca"
if the input is "abcaade" --> output "bcade"
If the input is "bacdeeede" --> output "bacde"
Simply the duplicate character gets replaced where maximum repetition  occurs

Comment: @SíðhärthPátñàík: Have you looked at my other answer? That explanation just repeats the same thing you've already said, almost word for word, and I still don't know whether I've guessed your meaning correctly, and I'm not going to try a third guess while I'm still waiting on a response to my second one.

Comment: Sir, you understood my question. But the above code in my console results 'cba' as you can see both 'c' and 'b' have same count perhaps that might be the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is an inelegant, ugly, inefficient, and almost certainly non-Pythonic solution but I think it does what you're looking for.

```
t = raw_input('Write your string here: ')

# Create a list initalized to 0 to store character counts
seen = dict()

# Make sure actually have a string
if len(t) < 1:
  print ""
else:
  prevChar = t[0]
  count = 0
  for char in t:
    if char == prevChar:
      count = count + 1
    else:
      # Check if the substring we just finished is the longest
      if count > seen.get(prevChar, 0):
        seen[prevChar] = count
      # Characters differ, restart
      count = 1
    prevChar = char

  # Append last character
  seen[prevChar] = count

  # Now let's build the string, appending the character when we find the longest version
  count = 0
  prevChar = t[0]
  finalString = ""
  for char in t:
    if char in finalString:
      # Make sure we don't append a char twice, append the first time we find the longest subsequence
      continue
    if char == prevChar:
      count = count + 1
    else:
      # Check if the substring we just finished is the longest
      if count == seen.get(prevChar, 0):
        finalString = finalString + prevChar
      # Characters differ, restart
      count = 1
    prevChar = char

  # Check the last character
  if count == seen[prevChar]:
    finalString= finalString + prevChar

  print finalString
```